# Can the unary & operator yield the address 0 (null pointer)?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, memory-address, null-pointer, unary-operator

C2x, 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators, Semantics, 3:

> The unary & operator yields the address of its operand.

A simple question: can the unary `&` operator yield the address `0` (null pointer)?

Any examples / experience?

Comment: No _object_ will return `&object` as 0.  Perhaps a computation or UB will.

Comment: By `0`, do you mean a null pointer or a pointer whose bit representation is all zeros?

Comment: @Brian Null pointer. Updated.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Meaning that an object cannot be placed at address 0? If yes, then why? In order to satisfy "is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function"?

Comment: @pmor Ding, ding, ding, you win the prize!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica If "a null pointer is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object" and "any two null pointers shall compare equal", then a null pointer is _not a pointer to object_. Is that correct?

Comment: @pmor More like "a null pointer is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to _any object or function_".  Yes, a _null pointer_ is not a pointer to an object.  To attempt to dereference a null pointer is UB.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Consider 6.5.6 Additive operator: "or one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type". But "a null pointer is not a pointer to an object". Hence, the `0 + (int*)0` leads to constraint violation. Many (if not all) compilers accept this code. Clang produces `warning: performing pointer arithmetic on a null pointer has undefined behavior`.

Comment: @pmor Wow, "Many [if not all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71134484/can-the-unary-operator-yield-the-address-0-null-pointer?noredirect=1#comment125800431_71134484) compilers accept this code." --> I am impressed by your depth of experience.  I have, at best, used 2 dozen of the many [C compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:C_(programming_language)_compilers).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Indeed, a hasty conclusion is here. Actually "accept" is not precise term here. Precise is "produce a diagnostic message". Clang does. (However, not for `(int*)(p - p) + 0`). Are you aware of other compilers, which diagnose this constraint violation?

Comment: @pmor Perhaps post as a question.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Meanwhile can you try to address [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71119812/1778275) question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C 2018 6.5.3.2 1 says:

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field…

If the operand is a function designator, it cannot be a null pointer, since C 2018 6.3.2.3 3 says a null pointer “is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function,” but a function designator that were a null pointer would compare equal to another (possibly different) null pointer because C 2018 6.5.9 6 says two null pointers compare equal.

If it is an lvalue that designates an object, then it cannot be a null pointer, for the same reason. (Note that 6.5.3.2 1 specifically refers to an lvalue that designates an object. In general, an lvalue is an expression that **potentially** designates an object. That is, it must have an object type. However, the constraint in 6.5.3.2 1 specifically tells us the operand must actually designate an object.)

That leaves the result of `[]` or unary `*`. The former is defined in terms of the latter, so we only need to consider unary `*`. C 2018 6.5.3.2 2 says “The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type,” but it does not require it to point to an actual object or function or to be non-null. 6.5.3.2 4 says “… If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object…” but does not explicitly say what the result is if the operand is a null pointer. It goes on to say “ If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary `*` operator is undefined.” The text there refers to note 106, which says “… Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary `*` operator are a null pointer, an address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the end of its lifetime.”

Therefore, there is no behavior defined by the C standard in which unary `&` would yield a null pointer. It may, of course, happen through behavior not defined by the standard.

Comment: If "a null pointer is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object" and "any two null pointers shall compare equal", then a null pointer is not a pointer to object. (What is an object?) Or is null pointer a pointer to a hypothetical "null object"? Hence, "a postfix expression followed by the `->` operator and an identifier" _does not_ designate a member of a structure object. Hence, `((struct some_struct *)0)->first_member` violates the semantics of the `->` operator. How can you comment?

Comment: The best answer.  Good last paragraph summary.

Comment: @pmor: The behavior of `((struct some_struct *)0)->first_member` is not defined by the C standard. Some C implementations use it in their own code because the C implementation supports it, not because the C standard does.

Answer (score 3):

It can. But you have to go out of your way to make it possible.

There are two ways to do this for an actual object:

1. Construct an object file or linker symbol file that you are linking against that exports a symbol at NULL. If you & on that you will get NULL.
2. Be libc on certain platforms. The first symbol you define is NULL. On at least one platform, the heap manager had to contend with this so it was carefully coded so the compiler would never observe the fact the heap HEAD pointer was stored at NULL.

Notice that both of these *waaaay* out of portable C, and that's the point. If you get `&` to return NULL you will know you did it. It's not happening by accident.

However there is another way: We can construct an expression containing no real objects where `&` returns a 0. Like this:

```
&(((struct some_struct *)0)->first_member)
```

Only seen in

```
#define offsetof(type, member) ((size_t)&(((type *)0)->member))
```

Don't do this. `#include <stddef>` and let the compiler define `offsetof`. There's a bug in this implementation.

Comment: `(struct some_struct *)0` is a _null pointer_ and so fails "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called
a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function."  `&(((struct some_struct *)0)->first_member)` relies on non-standard behavior.  Safe for an implementation to do, but not user code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: It's been debated to death; but there's a greater bug in it, in that it assumes something else. But in fact it's easier to do than the other two ways I give for `&` to yield a NULL.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant section of the standard is 6.3.2.3/3 (N2731), which states

> If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
> pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

Consequently, the result of `&` acting on any object is guaranteed to "compare unequal" with a null pointer.

Comment: A null pointer is different from a null pointer constant. This passage only says the result of converting a null pointer constant (which can be the source token `0`) to a pointer type compares unequal to a pointer to any object or function. There can be other representations of null pointers, and this passage does not say that they compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.